# Ruby Watir,Dijit, unable to locate table/tr/td and select value from table

Tags: ruby, watir, dijit.form

I am trying to select a value from the table of dropdown menu. But Watir always gave me the unlocate error when using table/tr/td.

I can't locate the element using

```
@browser.div(:id, 'wikiActionMenuLink_dropdown').element(:tag_name, 'table').element(:tag_name, 'tbody').element(:tag_name => 'td').text
```

But the output of code below returns true.

```
@browser.div(:id, 'wikiActionMenuLink_dropdown').element(:tag_name, 'table').element(:tag_name, 'tbody').element(:tag_name => 'td').exists?
```

I also tried

```
@browser.select_list(:id, 'wikiActionMenuLink_dropdown').select_value('Delete Wiki')
```

but got error "unable to locate element, using `{:id=>"wikiActionMenuLink_dropdown", :tag_name=>"select"}"`

Below the html. Could someone give me some suggestions?

```
<div id="wikiActionMenuLink_dropdown" class="dijitPopup dijitMenuPopup" style="visibility: visible; top: 123.75px; left: 1592px; right: auto; z-index: 1000; height: auto; overflow: visible; display: none;" role="region" aria-label="dijit_Menu_2" dijitpopupparent="">
<table id="dijit_Menu_2" class="dijit dijitReset dijitMenuTab`enter code here`le lotusPlain dijitMenu dijitMenuPassive" cellspacing="0" tabindex="0" role="menu" widgetid="dijit_Menu_2" style="top: 0px; visibility: visible;">
<tbody class="dijitReset" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
<tr id="dijit_MenuItem_15" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-label="Edit Wiki " title="Edit settings of this wiki." widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_15">
<tr id="dijit_MenuItem_16" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-label="Delete Wiki " title="Delete this wiki." widgetid="dijit_MenuItem_16">
</tbody>
</table>
<iframe class="dijitBackgroundIframe" src="javascript:""" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 100%; height: 100%;" tabindex="-1">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: `select_list` won't work because there's no `<select>` tag in the above code snippet.  Can you use the `id` attribute for the respective row as a locator?  For example: `b.tr(id: "dijit_MenuItem_16").click` (or even `b.tr(title: "Delete this wiki.").click`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andrey. I fixed it. The id was changing...

Answer (score 0):

Watir will only return the text of an element if the text is currently visible, regardless of whether the element exists. If you made the same call in your first example with .present? instead of .exists? it would return false.

For non-select/option dropdown interactions, you usually need to click the dropdown element first, and then once the options are visible, click on the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I found the bug. The id was changing depends on the browser and I am able to use indexing to locate the element.